# How can I Tell if a Type is a Functor?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, functor, type-traits

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) I have [`is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) to match function pointers, lambdas, and functors.

But what if I'm trapped on [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)? Do I have a type trait, or can I write one, which will match all of these?

I've tried [`is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) but that only works on function pointers.

Comment: It might be possible to use [existing ways to check the existence of a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) to detect whether `operator()` is defined for the given type.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have `std::invoke` as well, and won't be using pointers to members, so you can have a simple "`is_callable`" trait [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/B2w9i8) (Shorter than those other answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, `std::is_invocable` is a library function which requires no compiler support. You can just rip the implementation from an STL of your choice.

For example, you can find LLVM implementation of `__invokable` (to which `std::is_invocable` forwards all the logic in LLVM's STL) here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/5b3a49bdbd08775d0e6f9727221fe98946f6db44/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/type_traits

(I was thinking of extracting it and posting here, but it seems to be too big for a post. On a lighter note, I find difference in spelling - invocable vs invokable - amusing.)